# Gurobi Python Callback: I have trouble with retrieving the solution data: LP relaxation, Left nodes etc

Tags: python, callback, gurobi

I have a MILP model coded in python, using Gurobi.

When the code is terminated (Often by a time limit), I want to save some of the solution data, using gurobi callback. Mainly, I want to save "the LP relaxation objective" and "the left nodes". I use it like this:

This is the final lines:

```
model.optimize()
MyproblemLeftNodes = model.cbGet(GRB.Callback.MIP_NODLFT)
```

But I have the following errer:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute '_cbdata'
```

Also, if i use it as:

```
MyproblemLeftNodes = GRB.Callback.MIP_NODLFT
```

I will have the constant 3005.

Now, I am using this:

```
            def mycallback(myModel, where):
            if where == GRB.Callback.MIP:
                LPRelax = model.cbGet(GRB.Callback.MIP_OBJBST)

            return LPRelax
```

But still I do not know where to place it. After the model is optimized, or within the model? Both are not working with my current coding, responding:

```
'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Can anybody help me how to use callback correctly?

Comment: Why use a callback and not the model attributes?

Comment: Thanks a lot Greg. For the MIPGap, the attribute is working now. There was a problem with my variable. But I did not found attributes for left nodes and LP relaxation objective. Just NodeCount is available that reports the explored nodes, while I need to have the number of unexplored nodes.